# C++ Change the desktop with ChangeParametersInfo not working GetLastError returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop

I'm trying to use the following code to change the wall paper on a Windows 7 machine. I'm compiling with Multi Byte Character Set.

```
if(SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, L"c:\\temp\\extracted.png", SPIF_SENDCHANGE) != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Success !" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failure :(" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    system("title :(");
}
```

I have no idea of why this is not working since it doesn't return an error code (GetLastError gives 0). No need to say that the wall paper remains unchanged.

EDIT: tried to change to this and to put a bmp file instead.

```
int error(0);
if(SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, L"c:\\temp\\extracted.bmp", SPIF_SENDCHANGE) != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Success !" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    error = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "Failure :(" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
    system("title :(");
}
system("pause");
```

Output in console is Failure :( followed by Error: 0

Comment: Does SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER accept .png files?

Comment: From what I've found on the internet it looks like it does. MSDN doesn't gives infos : "
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER
0x0014

 
Note  When the SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER flag is used, SystemParametersInfo returns TRUE unless there is an error (like when the specified file doesn't exist)."

Comment: I'd try it with a .bmp file, just to check.

Comment: I'm going to try and I will write the result here.

Comment: You need to save `GetLastError()` immediately after the call to `SystemParametersInfoW` and before `cout`. `cout` can reset it.

Comment: @PaulSanders it seems indeed like the function only accepts bitmaps as stated [here] (http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/s/systemparametersinfo.html) &quot;SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20Set the current desktop wallpaper bitmap.&#160;uiParam&#160;must be 0.&#160;pvParam&#160;is a String holding the filename of the bitmap file to use as the wallpaper.&quot;

Comment: Try with `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE` as the flags value.

Comment: I tried updating the flags, no changes.

Comment: In that case all I can think of is the file doesn't actually exist or can't be read for some reason. In any event it's probably better to use the `IActiveDesktop` interface these days.

Comment: Your code works for me on Windows 10 desktop. Output in console is Success !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the advice on the comments I abandoned ChangeParametersInfo and implemented this quick function I found. Worked instantly.

```
void  SetWallpaper(LPCWSTR file) 
 {
    CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    IActiveDesktop* desktop;
    HRESULT status = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ActiveDesktop, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IActiveDesktop, (void**)&desktop);
    WALLPAPEROPT wOption;
    ZeroMemory(&wOption, sizeof(WALLPAPEROPT));
    wOption.dwSize = sizeof(WALLPAPEROPT);
    wOption.dwStyle = WPSTYLE_CENTER;
    status = desktop->SetWallpaper(file, 0);
    status = desktop->SetWallpaperOptions(&wOption, 0);
    status = desktop->ApplyChanges(AD_APPLY_ALL);
    desktop->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Usage

```
SetWallpaper(L"c:\\temp\\extracted.png");
```

This is so much easier than bothering with the old one. Still wondering why it wasn't giving an error. Hope this will help someone else.
Thanks for the advices everyone.

Comment: Don't forget error handling. If `CoInitializeEx()` returns a failure `HRESULT` other than `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`, `CoCreateInstance()` and other COM calls are going to fail as well. And don't call `CoUninitialize()` if `CoInitializeEx()` fails. And if `CoCreateInstance()` returns a failure `HRESULT`, the address stored in the `desktop` variable is indeterminate and cannot be used.

Comment: `HRESULT status = CoInitializeEx(...); bool doUninit = SUCCEEDED(status); if (doUninit || (status == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)) { status = CoCreateInstance(..., &desktop); if (SUCCEEDED(status)) { ... desktop->Release(); } if (doUninit) CoUninitialize(); }`

Comment: In fact, your function should not be calling `CoInitializeEx()` and `CoUninitialize()` at all, it is the calling thread's responsibility to call them during its own startup and cleanup: `CoInitializeEx(...); ... SetWallpaper(...); ... CoUninitialize();`

Comment: I still have a small problem "wOption.dwStyle = WPSTYLE_STRETCH;" has no effect, by that I mean it's always centered even when I modify this param any ideas why ?

Comment: I just saw the last part what do you mean indeterminate ?

Comment: Your "new code" is wrong. `CoCreateInstance()` will never return `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`, only `CoInitialize/Ex()` can return that, so `doUninit` has no meaning for `CoCreateInstance()`. And your code does not call `SetWallpaper()` if `CoInitializeEx()` does return `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`, which is not a failure condition, just a condition that warrants skipping `CoUninitialize()`.  And you are calling `Release()` if `CoCreateInstance()` fails. Use what I showed you in my previous comment

Comment: Btw thanks for the help I have no experience with this API so sorry if my questions are a bit dumb.

Comment: You are still calling `desktop->Release()` if `CoCreateInstance()` fails. And GET RID of `doUninit` inside of `SetWallpaper()`, it doesn't belong there. And you are still calling `CoUnitialize()` if `CoInitializeEx()` returns `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`, don't do that.

Comment: `SetWallpaper()` is fine now, but you are still calling `CoUninitialize()` if `CoInitializeEx()` returns `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`. DON'T call `CoUninitialize()` UNLESS `CoInitializeEx()` returns EITHER `S_OK` or `S_FALSE`, both of which are handled by `SUCCEEDED()`.

Comment: Ok I'm using your code but can you please elaborate on what you meant when you said the  desktop is is not usable ? I think I get it now. I have to read documentation on COM objects.

Comment: If `CoCreateInstance()` fails, `desktop` will not be pointing at a valid `IActiveDesktop` object in memory. It SHOULD get set to NULL on failure, but just in case, don't rely on that behavior. Just don't use `desktop` at all UNLESS `CoCreateInstance()` returns `S_OK`, which is handled by `SUCCEEDED()`.

Comment: Ok seems to be working now. I found that IActiveDesktop is a COM object but I don't really know what that is as you can see I am struggling quite a bit. Could you please link your documentation ?

Comment: [Component Object Model (COM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/component-object-model--com--portal), [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex), [`CoUninitialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize), [`IActiveDesktop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nn-shlobj_core-iactivedesktop), [Using the Active Desktop Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/lwef/active-desktop-interface)

Comment: Well thanks for everything, I am not really sure of why the handling solved the problem but everything is working perfect. Have a nice day.